# Spring Boot: When application.properties and application.yml are loaded by a spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot

I wish to log that the application is loading an application-profile.propeties or the application.yml. How to do it. In which method, can i listen to that and detect that it loaded it successfully or it fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could log the loaded property sources by adding a component listening for the `ApplicationReadyEvent`

```
@Component
public class LoadedConfigFileListener implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent>, Ordered {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoadedConfigFileListener.class);

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
        MutablePropertySources propertySources = event.getApplicationContext().getEnvironment().getPropertySources();
        Iterator<PropertySource<?>> propertySourceIterator = propertySources.iterator();
        propertySourceIterator.forEachRemaining(propertySource -> logger.info("Successfully loaded: \"{}\" into application context", propertySource.getName()));
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return ConfigFileApplicationListener.DEFAULT_ORDER + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nilson but i didn't need to log the file content. I wish to check if the file application-profile.properties is successfully loaded.

Comment: Using the same approach you could list or iterate all the loaded property sources and check the ones you like.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to debug loading properties, add following environment variable (command line parameter when launching Java code):

```
logging.level.org.springframework.core.env=DEBUG
```

You can see in log lines for example:

```
2017-05-23 08:37:00.773 DEBUG 26152 --- [           main] o.s.core.env.MutablePropertySources      : Adding [applicationConfig: [file:./application.properties]] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
...
2017-05-23 08:37:00.774 DEBUG 26152 --- [           main] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Found key 'server.port' in [applicationConfig: [file:./application.properties]] with type [String]
...
2017-05-23 08:37:02.087 DEBUG 26152 --- [           main] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Found key 'spring.datasource.url' in [applicationConfig: [file:./application.properties]] with type [String]
```

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with the initial log output of a spring boot app?  One of the first 5 lines when I start a spring boot app fresh out of the box is:

`2017-05-23 23:09:59 INFO  e.r.t.MyApplication - No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default`

That log output tells me the default (application.yml) properties file was loaded.  For all profiles that are active, the corresponding properties files will be loaded.

For example, if this was my log output:

`2017-05-23 23:14:32 INFO  e.r.t.MyApplication - The following profiles are active: cloud, dev, special`

then ***ALL*** of these properties files would be loaded (Note, you can interchange .properties and .yml):

`application.yml`

`application-cloud.yml`

`application-dev.yml`

`application-special.yml`

FURTHERMORE, remember that Spring Boot allows property overriding in the order the properties files are read, so the last loaded property file wins.  In this case, if I declared a property, call it `my.property` in all 4 of those above properties files, only the value in `application-special.yml` would be loaded since it was the last applied profile.

Answer (score 0):

**24.4 Profile-specific properties**

See the http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties

In addition to **application.properties** files, profile-specific properties can also be defined using the naming convention application-{profile}.properties.

The Environment has a set of default profiles (by default [default]) which are used if no active profiles are set (i.e. if no profiles are explicitly activated then properties from application-default.properties are loaded).

Profile-specific properties are loaded from the same locations as standard application.properties, with profile-specific files always overriding the non-specific ones irrespective of whether the profile-specific files are inside or outside your packaged jar.

If several profiles are specified, a last wins strategy applies. For example, profiles specified by the spring.profiles.active property are added after those configured via the SpringApplication API and therefore take precedence.

Eg: you can set profile name in appliation.properties

```
spring.profiles.active=dev
```

so dev profile will be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/72703413/173149

```yaml
logging.level:
    # For Spring Boot 1.x.x.
    "org.springframework.core.env": trace
    # For Spring Boot 1.x.x-2.3.x.
    "org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener": trace
    # For Spring Boot 2.4.x-3.x.x.
    "org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironment": trace
```

Then Spring Framework log it as:

```
TRACE ...ConfigDataEnvironment
  Adding imported property source 'Config resource 'file [application.yml]' via location 'optional:file:./''
TRACE ...ConfigDataEnvironment
  Adding imported property source 'Config resource 'class path resource [application-h2-test.yml]' via location 'optional:classpath:/''
TRACE ...ConfigDataEnvironment
  Adding imported property source 'Config resource 'class path resource [application.yml]' via location 'optional:classpath:/''
```