# How to find location of application.yml loaded by spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configuration

For configuring a spring boot application I can control which configuration/properties file (let's say `application.yml`) is loaded by placing the file in one of the locations where spring scans for such files (./config/, cwd, classpath:config/, classpath root). I can also point to a specific location using CLI (`spring.config.location`) or environment variables.

How can I find out where the properties file(s) was finally loaded from during runtime? I wish to check if the user specified/used his own config file or if the provided config file was used.

I am using spring 5.2.2 and springboot 2.2.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a programmatic way of doing it, but there's a fantastic link in Spring's documentation which shows all `17(!) default property locations`, including the order they are being read in.

You might want to check it out here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config

Comment: Thanks, interesting read. I guess it would anyway smell to take runtime decisions based on the config location given the amout of configuration possibilities. My goal was to check if the user ran the application *as intended* or if he/she modified some properties compared to the `application.yml` file that came with the deployed application package.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it's possible to find that after the application is started.

However, you can check the debug log output for 'org.springframework.boot' during startup.

To quickly enable debug logging to console you can run the spring boot application with `--debug` on the command line or `debug=true` in application.yml. The config files found by Spring Boot should be in the first few lines.

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.6.RELEASE)

2020-04-08 15:05:22.736  INFO 19079 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication on Dwalin with PID 19079 (/home/geertp/repos/github.com/greyfairer/spring-boot-test/demo/target/classes started by geertp in /home/geertp/repos/github.com/greyfairer/spring-boot-test/demo)
2020-04-08 15:05:22.736  INFO 19079 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-04-08 15:05:22.737 DEBUG 19079 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Loading source class com.example.demo.DemoApplication
2020-04-08 15:05:22.765 DEBUG 19079 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener  : Loaded config file 'file:/home/geertp/repos/github.com/greyfairer/spring-boot-test/demo/target/classes/application.yml' (classpath:/application.yml)
```

Answer (score 0):

As with Spring Boot 2.4 the `ConfigFileApplicationListener` was deprecated the new one should be used: `ConfigDataEnvironment`:

```yaml
logging.level:
    # For Spring Boot 1.x.x.
    "org.springframework.core.env": trace
    # For Spring Boot 1.x.x-2.3.x.
    "org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener": trace
    # For Spring Boot 2.4.x-3.x.x.
    "org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironment": trace
    "org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor": trace
```